# vim indent: align function arguments

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

The default alignment in vim (using "=") aligns my code as:

```
void my_loooong_function (int arg1,
        int arg2,
        int arg3
        )
```

However, I wish to align with all arguments starting at same line, as:

```
void my_loooong_function (int arg1,
                          int arg2,
                          int arg3
                         )
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make `==` work as you wish, you need to set `cinoptions` appropriately:

```
:set cino+=(0
```

Full documentation of the possible values can be found via `:help cinoptions-values`, and in particular `:help cino-(` to control the indentation inside unclosed parentheses.

The setting will also affect the autoindent behaviour (for example, when you enter a carriage return after opening a bracket).

This can, of course, be added to your vimrc or an ftplugin to automatically set this value for certain filetypes.

Comment: How do you make it indent with spaces instead of tabs?

Answer (score 6):

Try vim plugin [`Tabular`](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular):

```
:Tabularize /\v[( )](int|$)
```

---

Tutorial: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/